# Is the relation $e^{At} = Pe^{Jt} P^{-1}$ valid for a Jordan form?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Imagine you have a system of equations of the form:
$$
\mathbf {\dot{x}} = A \mathbf{x}
$$
And $A$ cannot be diagonalized, so you find it's Jordan form:
$$
A = P J P^{-1} \\ \; \\
J  = \begin{pmatrix} 
\lambda_1 & 1 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_3 & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0&  \dots & \lambda_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The solution of the differential equation is:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = e^{At}\mathbf{x_0}
$$
My question is: If the matrix $A$ was diagonalizable, then:
$$
e^{At} = P \begin{pmatrix} 
e^{\lambda_1t} & 0 & 0 & \dots  & 0 \\
0 & e^{\lambda_2 t} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{\lambda_3 t} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots &\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0&  \dots & e^{\lambda_n t} \\
\end{pmatrix} P^{-1}
$$
because:
$$
e^{At} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(At)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(PDP^{-1})^n}{n!}t^n = P \left ( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{D^n}{n!}t^n \right )P^{-1} = P e^{Dt} P^{-1}
$$
but, is this last relation:
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(PJP^{-1})^n}{n!}t^n = P \left ( \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{J^n}{n!}t^n \right )P^{-1} = P e^{Jt} P^{-1}
$$
still apply for a Jordan form? I know that when you sum all the terms involved in $e^{Jt}$, polynomials of $t$ will appear apart from the exponential related to the eigenvalue: $e^{\lambda_k t}$. But, is this still valid?

Comment: Yes. It is true term by term and the series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, although there is a bit of checking you need to do first. First, your Jordan form is slightly wrong. $J$ should be a block diagonal matrix

$$
J = \begin{bmatrix}
J_1 & \;     & \; \\
\;  & \ddots & \; \\ 
\;  & \;     & J_p\end{bmatrix}
$$

where each block $J_i$ is given by

$$
J_i = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_i & 1            & \;     & \;  \\
\;        & \lambda_i    & \ddots & \;  \\
\;        & \;           & \ddots & 1   \\
\;        & \;           & \;     & \lambda_i  
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
In particular, we only have ones above the diagonals within blocks corresponding to a single eigenvalue each. The matrix exponential of this block diagonal matrix is given by

$$
e^{tJ} = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{tJ_1} & \;     & \; \\
\;  & \ddots & \; \\ 
\;  & \;     & e^{tJ_p}\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now we just have to compute the matrix exponential of a single Jordan block.

We decompose the Jordan block $J_i$ into diagonal and off-diagonal terms, $J_i = D_i + N_i$, where $D_i = \lambda_i I$ and

$$
N_i = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1            & \;     & \;  \\
\;        & 0   & \ddots & \;  \\
\;        & \;           & \ddots & 1   \\
\;        & \;           & \;     & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
These matrices commute, so we can use the fact that $e^{A+B} = e^Ae^B$ for commuting matrices $A$ and $B$. Notice that the Jordan form you wrote does not satisfy this property since it is essential that the diagonal terms are the same for them to commute. Also notice that $N_i$ is nilpotent, so $N_i^k = 0_{k\times k}$, where $k$ is the size of the Jordan block. We can now calculate the matrix exponential.

$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{tJ_i} &= e^{tD_i + tN_i} = e^{tD_i}e^{tN_i}\\
&= e^{\lambda_i t}I_{k\times k} \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{t^jN_i^j} 
{j!}\right) \\
&= e^{\lambda_i t}\left(\sum_{j=0}^k \frac{t^jN_i^j} 
{j!}\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
which is a vector of polynomials in $t$ times $e^{\lambda_i t}$, which is what we would expect. One can then apply the $P$ and $P^{-1}$ from both sides to obtain the final result.